Does dbt cloud support more than one job dependency
I have a scheduling question regarding dbt Cloud. I need to set up Job AB to run once a week on Wednesdays, but only after Job A has completed. For context, Job A runs every day. I’ve tried using the available Trigger options, but this results in duplicate runs. How can I accomplish this without adding logic to the actual model? I tried to add a macro that would check for the day of the week as command 1 and added the model refresh as command 2 but this did not really do anything. Any insight is appreciated

which dbt version you are in?
DBT 1.7 both team and enterprise gives option of job chaining.
To avoid duplicate runs, you can schedule job A to run Monday through Sunday excluding wednesdays as it will run as part of AB job.
Cron schedule for that could be 0 0 * * 1-2,4-7
After that you could set up AB with job chaining like below as given in documentation

